# dynamically set radiobuttons based on text field adobe

Tags: javascript, adobe

I am very new at writing script so excuse my lack of understanding.  I have 2 radio buttons in adobe pro.  I would like them to dynamically switch based on how another text box is populated.  The text box will say either "Yes" or "No".  I really don't know where to start with the buttons.  I would think they would be easy, but I am having a lot of trouble.  I am not sure if I should put code in the validate tab of the textbox, or if I should use the actions tab in the radio button.  Any code from scratch would help since I haven't been able to find any consistent answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple code after more research.  I put this in my calculation field of the text box.  It works great.  I did have some parameters before this.  The Text box used told me the parameters to to make this true or not.

this.getField("CHECK").checkThisBox(0, (event.value=="Yes"));
this.getField("CHECK1").checkThisBox(0, (event.value=="No"));